# input type=file на английском языке

Tags: html, css

Есть такая верстка

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" class="form-control">
```

Но показывает почему то на русском хотя сайт на английском.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так что бы показывало на английском? [Вот пример](http://magicclean.dk/pages/view/career)

Comment: Язык и вид виджета зависит от браузера, а не сайта. Если операционная система будет использовать английский интерфейс, то и надпись на кнопке будет английской.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input[type='file']` - одна из самых каверзных вещей в смысле стилистики и обработки.
Браузер практически никак не даёт его кастомизировать (по очевидным причинам).

---

Путь самурая - скрыть оригинальный элемент (слава Аллаху, хоть возможность скрыть оставили) и вывести своё, при клике на которое, запускаем скрытый элемент:

```css
.uploadButton {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    background: #3df;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.uploadButton:hover {
    background: #3ce;
}
.uploadButton div{
  color: #00097d;
}
```

```html
<label for="uploadbtn" class="uploadButton">Загрузить файл<div></div></label>
<input style="opacity: 0; z-index: -1;" multiple type="file" name="upload" id="uploadbtn" onchange='document.querySelector(".uploadButton div").innerHTML = Array.from(this.files).map(f => f.name).join("<br />")' />
```

Comment: Хороший пример, но самый главный минус этого способа, то что не отображается название прикрепленного файла

Comment: @AndRey, это легко фиксится прямыми руками, тут лишь основа, пример.